# NullFirst no funciona con TFDTable de FireDAC

Tags: sql-server, oracle, delphi

Me encuentro trabajando con la versión XE7 de Delphi, *FireDAC* y los manejadores de bases de datos *SQL Server* y *Oracle*. Utilizando el componente de FireDAC `TFDTable` note que, al realizar un `Last` o un `First`, obtenía diferentes resultados para ambos manejadores.

Investigando y publicando en foros encontré que se daba debido a los nulos, porque *Oracle* los maneja de distinta manera que *SQL Server*; pude notar que cuando en *SQL Server* se utiliza un `DESC` en *Oracle* se debe de colocar `DESC NULLS LAST` y cuando en *SQL Server* se coloca `ASC` en Oracle debe de ser `NULLS FIRST`; esto para obtener los registros en el mismo orden.

Encontré la propiedad `Options` (`TFDIndex.Options`), que cuenta con los valores de `soNullFirst` y `soDescNullLast`, entre otros. Al utilizar `soDescNullLast` ya pude obtener el mismo resultado en ambos manejadores de BD, pero cuando utilizo `soNullFirst` sigo obteniendo resultados distintos, mi código es el siguiente:

```
    var i: Integer;
begin
    i:= 1;
    try
        FDTable.Active:=False;
        case i of
        1: begin
            FDTable.TableName:='Personas';
            FDTable.IndexName:='Personas4';
            FDTable.Active:=True;
            
            FDTable.Indexes[0].Options:=[soNullFirst];
            
            FDTable.First;
            FDTable.Next;
            FDTable.Next;
            FDTable.Next;
            FDTable.Next;
            
            ShowMessage(FDTable.FieldByName('ID').Value);
           end;
        2: begin
            FDTable.TableName:='Personas';
            FDTable.IndexName:='Personas4';
            FDTable.Active:=True;
            
            FDTable.Indexes[0].Options:=[soDescNullLast];
            
            FDTable.Last;
            FDTable.Prior;
            FDTable.Prior;
            FDTable.Prior;
            FDTable.Prior;
            
            ShowMessage(FDTable.FieldByName('ID').Value);
           end;
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a saber que es lo que estoy haciendo mal o porque no funciona al utilizar `soNullFirst`, gracias.

Comment: Para responder de manera correcta, me gustaría ver ver el código con el que creas el índice `Personas4`.

Comment: El índice lo tengo creado en la base de datos, en Delphi solo lo traigo por su nombre, solo tiene un campo y este campo tiene valores nulos, ya intente también asignar la propiedad antes de abrir la tabla pero esto me arroja un erro de "argumento fuera del rango"

Comment: La propiedad `IndexName` e `Indexes` sirven para trabajar con _indices del lado del cliente_, es decir, son índices creados en el espacio de memoria de tu programa por FireDac, por un lado, para mantener un orden consistente de los registros y por otro para hacer más eficiente el acceso a tus datos, pero nada tienen que ver con los índices que puedan existir a nivel de base de datos. Escribiré una respuesta para explicarme.

Comment: Espero tu respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que aclaraste en comentarios de la pregunta, estás intentando utilizar un índice creado a nivel de base de datos.

Sin embargo, los índices a nivel de base de datos existen para uso del motor de base de datos como tal, que los utiliza para optimizar el acceso a la información: *joins*, filtrado, ordenamiento y aplicación de condiciones, a manera de producir de manera óptima los resultados de las consultas y otras operaciones realizadas.

Por otro lado, FireDac, al igual que otras capas de conexión:

- Se comunica con la base de datos a través del lenguaje SQL en el que, generalmente, no se tiene acceso a los índices subyacentes en la base de datos y, si lo hay, es solo a nivel de *hints* dados a la base de datos para forzarla a utilizar un índice que, según quien escribe la consulta, es más optimo que los seleccionados por el propio motor para ejecutar una consulta.
- La capa de conexión provee de mecanismos para ordenar y optimizar el acceso a los datos del lado del cliente, es decir tu propia aplicación.

En el caso de *FireDac*, la propiedad `IndexName` e `Indexes` sirven para trabajar con indices del lado del cliente, es decir, son estructuras creadas en el espacio de memoria de tu programa por *FireDac*, por un lado, para mantener un orden consistente de navegación por los registros y, por otro, para hacer más eficiente el acceso a los datos cuando se utilizan métodos de localización de registros.

Estas estructuras de creación y uso local nada tienen que ver con los índices que puedan existir a nivel de base de datos.

Si no creas índices en tus DataSets (`TFDTable` hereda de `TDataSet`), los datos estarán disponibles en el orden en el que se recibieron del motor. En el caso de `TFDTable`, el orden es, básicamente, aleatorio (aunque los motores suelen devolver los registros en algún orden lógico para ellos).

Por eso mismo, generalmente se recomienda utilizar componentes donde TU escribes la consulta, de manera que puedas forzar el orden en el que el motor devuelve los datos, que suele ser suficiente para muchos usos de los mismos, y dejar la creación de índices locales solo para los casos donde el volumen/uso de datos lo amerita.

De esa forma, si utilizas un `TFDQuery` y colocas en su propiedad SQL una consulta que devuelva los datos en el mismo orden para cada motor, podrías resolver el problema que tienes, que es simplemente ver los datos en el mismo orden del lado del cliente, para ambos motores.

Podrías entonces, para SQL Server, escribir en la propiedad SQL:

```
select * from MiTabla order by Campo1 desc, Campo2 desc
```

Mientras para Oracle escribirías

```
select * from MiTabla order by Campo1 desc nulls last, Campo2 desc nulls last
```

O bien, puedes escribir exactamente la misma consulta para ambos, pues las sentencias son soportadas por los motores:

Cuando quieres un orden descendente:

```
select * from MiTabla order by Campo1 desc nulls last, Campo2 desc nulls last
```

Cuando quieres ordenar de manera ascendente:

```
select * from MiTabla order by Campo1 asc nulls first, Campo2 asc nulls first
```

O incluso la combinación de ambos:

```
select * from MiTabla order by Campo1 asc nulls first, Campo2 desc nulls last
```

De esta manera, no creas ningún índice local, simplemente abres, recorres y listo:

```
FDQuery.SQL.Text := 'select * from MiTabla order by Campo1 asc nulls first, Campo2 desc nulls last';
FDQuery.Open;
while not FDQuery.EOF do
begin
  ShowMessage(FDQuery.FieldByName('Nombres').AsString);
  FDQuery.Next;
end;
```

Otra posible solución, es crear de manera simple un único índice local valiéndote de la propiedad [`IndexFieldNames`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.IndexFieldNames), por ejemplo:

```
FDTable.TableName:='Personas';
FDTable.Open;
FDTable.IndexFieldNames := 'Nombres;Apellidos';
```

O bien, para orden descendente:

```
FDTable.TableName:='Personas';
FDTable.Open;
FDTable.IndexFieldNames := 'Nombres:D;Apellidos:D';
```

En este caso, FireDac ordenará los datos de manera local, independientemente de cómo hayan llegado desde el motor (OJO, que esto puede ser difícil de optimizar si el *dataset* tiene un volumen grande de datos, aunque en tu código actual no haría mayor diferencia, pues asumo que siempre traes todos los datos desde el servidor al hacer `Open`).

Si quieres tener un mayor control o varios índices creados a la vez, puedes utilizar el método [`AddIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.AddIndex)

```
FDTable.DeleteIndexes;
FDTable.TableName:='Personas';
FDTable.Open;
FDTable.AddIndex('MiIndice', 'Nombres;Apellidos', '', [soNoCase, soNullFirst]);
FDTable.IndexesActive := True;
FDTable.IndexName := 'MiIndice';
```

Comment: Ok, entiendo tus puntos pero entonces porque cuando utilizo descNullLast ahí si me los ordena de la misma manera en ambos gestores? y SQL Server no soporta desc nulls last ni nulls first, el comportamiento de ASC y DESC es como si lo tuviera pero no se pueden utilizar esas palabras reservadas

Comment: No sabría responder por qué lo hace, puedo suponer que quizás se crea un índice local al vuelo, o tiene algún efecto secundario, que quizás pueda ser un bug en la capa de conexión. Considero que mi respuesta brinda información suficiente para que hagas tus propias pruebas y enlaza la documentación, donde está explicado a detalle como funcionan los componentes.

Comment: He probado creando el índice con AddIndex pero sigo obteniendo resultados distintos en ambos gestores :(

Comment: ¿Estas segura que se está utilizando el índice local? Pregunto porque una vez se utiliza, el orden en que se recibieron los registros del motor ya no es relevante.

Comment: Lo tengo de esta manera:
FDTable.DeleteIndexes;
FDTable.TableName:='Personas';
FDTable.Open;
FDTable.AddIndex('Personas7', 'Apellido', '', [soNoCase, soNullFirst]);
FDTable.IndexesActive := True;
FDTable.IndexName := 'Personas7';
FDTable.Active:=True;
FDTable.First;
ShowMessage(FDTable.FieldByName('ID').Value);

Comment: Probe solo utilizando el soNoCase y en esa opción si le aplica a la consulta un Upper(Apellido) pero el nullFirst lo ignora por completo

Comment: Recién hice una prueba con _SQL Server_ y en orden ascendente siempre aparecen los `NULL` primero, es decir, es como si `soNullFirst` siempre estuviera aplicado y no existe un _flag_ que haga lo contrario. En mi opinión, haría falta. Si quieres tener control específico del orden de los `NULL`, te recomiendo entonces utilizar `TFDQuery` y controlarlo desde la base de datos.

Comment: De hecho, dependiendo del orden que te interese, puedes tener que recurrir a algún truco pues, como ya habías dicho, efectivamente SQL Server no soporta el modificador `NULLS FIRST/LAST` en la cláusula `order by` (cosa que acabo de descubrir). Siendo parte del estándar desde el 92 (o algo así) daba por hecho que lo tendría. Justo encontré [este artículo](https://dba-presents.com/index.php/databases/sql-server/36-order-by-and-nulls-last-in-sql-server) (en inglés), que podría ayudarte con el tema.

Comment: Si es justo a la conclusión que estoy llegando, acabo de leer una nota de que TFDTable siempre ignora el soNullFirst y el soDescNullLast dejandole ese trabajo al SGBD, y el que si me devolviera los mismos resultados con el soDescNullLast fue por un error de registros, porque he realizado más pruebas y ya tampoco me los devuelve iguales, muchas gracias por el apoyo